# Windows Update API Memory Leak in Code

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-update

I am developing an application in C# to aid in a process that my company uses to configure new PCs before adding them to our domain, for offices all around the country. I am currently at a phase where I need to automate Windows Updates without any feedback from the user.

I have all of the Windows Update code put together in a console application. But I noticed when there are a LOT of updates (60 to 100+) the TrustedInstaller process ends up using over 1.5GB of RAM (after about 1hr+ during the install process), although the installation of the updates eventually does finish (2-4 hours later) I feel like 1.5GB of physical memory is just too much (even though this will be the only productive process running at the time).

In the interest in ensuring my code runs optimally would someone mind taking a look for me? I am very new to the Windows Update API(wuapi.dll) and there is very little documentation on the internet.

Here is the snippet of code (at the very bottom of my "program" class) that initiates and runs the installation of downloaded updates:

```
using WUApiLib


        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Installing Updates...");

        IUpdateInstaller installer = uSession.CreateUpdateInstaller();
        installer.Updates = updatesToInstall;            
        IInstallationResult installationRes = installer.Install();
        List<object> successUpdates = new List<object>();
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < updatesToInstall.Count; i++)
        {
            if (installationRes.GetUpdateResult(i).HResult == 0)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Installed: " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                successUpdates.Add(i);
            }
            else
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
            "{0} out of {1} updates installed successfully!",successUpdates.Count() ,updatesToInstall.Count);
```

And below is my entire code for searching, downloading, and installing the updates (Console.Readkey() methods are in there simply for testing):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WUApiLib;
using System.Management;

namespace WUConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {           
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                "Checking for Windows Updates...");
            try
            {
                UpdateSession uSession = new UpdateSession();
                IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
                ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and BrowseOnly=0");


            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Available Updates:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-" + update.Title);
            }
            if (uResult.Updates.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Windows is up to date!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }


            int updateCount = uResult.Updates.Count;

            if (updateCount == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Finished searching for updates. {0} update found.", updateCount);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Finished searching for updates. {0} updates found.", updateCount);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            if (updateCount == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Downloading {0} Windows Update...", updateCount);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "Downloading {0} Windows Updates...", updateCount);
            }           
            UpdateDownloader downloader = uSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();
            downloader.Updates = uResult.Updates;
            downloader.Download();

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Updates Downloaded Successfully!");
            UpdateCollection updatesToInstall = new UpdateCollection();
            foreach(IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
            {
                if (update.IsDownloaded)
                    update.AcceptEula();
                    updatesToInstall.Add(update);
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Installing Updates...");

            IUpdateInstaller installer = uSession.CreateUpdateInstaller();
            installer.Updates = updatesToInstall;            
            IInstallationResult installationRes = installer.Install();
            List<object> successUpdates = new List<object>();
            Console.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < updatesToInstall.Count; i++)
            {
                if (installationRes.GetUpdateResult(i).HResult == 0)
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Installed: " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                    successUpdates.Add(i);
                }
                else
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                "{0} out of {1} updates installed successfully!",successUpdates.Count() ,updatesToInstall.Count);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "1");
            Console.ReadKey();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");
                 }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Windows Update failed: " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any feedback/ pointers on this would be greatly appreciated, as I know there is not much documentation out there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: where in your code are you `Disposing` of any of the Object Instances you've created... I would start there

Comment: You are also boxing `int`s  by storing them in a `List<object>` for no apparent reason.

Comment: Good call, Thanks Method I'm also fairly junior and am still even learning the basics. I know disposing needs to be used in code, but am still learning about what parts of code need to be disposed and what not. I will look further into disposing of objects after they are used.  And Preston, I assume I just need to make the list type `int` instead of `object`?

Comment: Yes, just change the type of `successUpdates` to `List<int>` and you'll avoid boxing. Regarding disposing objects, *any* class that implements `IDisposable` needs to be disposed when you're done with an instance. The easiest way to achieve this is with a `using` block (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) - if you don't dispose `IDisposable` instances, you *will* wind up with memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks so much guys I really appreciate the help... I'm gonna have to do some research `IDisposable`!